# How to add a template - so that i can choose a different menu for some pages

Tags: customization, menus, templates

Hi I would like to know how I can add a template just to choose a different menu for some pages,

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new template with a different header.

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php 
  //different header for different menu
  get_header('header_name'); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```